# Can I enter the UK with my family visit visa while my settlement visa was refused and waiting for the tribunal court hearing?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, denial-of-entry

I was denied entry clearance for a family settlement visa as a spouse and after appeal I'm waiting for the hearing date in.court.

Can I enter the UK with my existing family visit visa, which I got two years back, to see my husband and child currently in the UK? It's valid for 5 years.

Comment: Are you certain that your family visit visa wasn't curtailed when your settlement application was refused? If it wasn't, there is a risk of it being cancelled by an Immigration Officer when you present for entry at the border. When was your refusal and when was the appeal filed?

Comment: I have received passport without any charges in visit visa page. Do I don’t know it was cancelled or or not. Refusal was in 8th May and appeal filed in 31st May this year

Comment: I mean no change in visa page

Comment: Understood; btw, it can take up to 12 weeks for the visa section to send your appeal bundle to the Tribunal, another 6-8 weeks, or longer, for a hearing (either oral or on paper without an oral hearing). Going for a visit shouldn't be a problem, but there's no way for anyone to predict what might occur when seeking entry. Because of the failed application, it may not go well: you could be refused entry or allowed to enter for a limited period. Just be prepared to spend some time at the border.

Comment: Ah ok. So there is a possibility of cancellation of visit visa or deportation at border too?

Comment: Yes, but it would not be a deportation, rather an entry refusal, very different. Depending on the reasons for the settlement refusal, it may be wiser to wait for the appeal decision.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to make certain that your Family visit visa wasn't curtailed when your settlement application was refused. If it wasn't, there is a risk of it being cancelled by an Immigration Officer where you to present for entry at the border.

As the refusal was in 8 May and the appeal filed on 31 May, understand that it can take up to 12 weeks for the visa section to send your appeal bundle to the Tribunal, another 6-8 weeks, or longer, for a hearing (either oral or on paper without an oral hearing).

Going for a visit might not be a problem, but there's no way to predict what could occur when seeking entry. Because of the failed application, it may not go well. You could be refused entry or allowed to enter for a limited period; either would another strike against you on your immigration record. Depending on the reasons for the settlement refusal, it may be wiser to wait for the appeal decision.